# sscanf_s doesn't return first character of string

Tags: c, string, windows, char, scanf

I'm trying to find the first string (max 4 characters) in a comma-separated list of strings inside a C char-array.

I'm trying to achieve this by using `sscanf_s` (under Windows) and the format-control string `%[^,]`:

```
char mystring[] = "STR1,STR2";
char temp[5];

if (sscanf_s(mystring, "%[^,]", temp, 5) != 0) {
    if (strcmp(temp, "STR1") == 0) { return 0; }
    else if (strcmp(temp, "STR2") == 0) { return 1; }
    else { return -1; }
}
```

After calling `sscanf_s` the content of temp is not `STR1` but `\0TR1` (`\0` being the ASCII-interpretation of `0`). And the value `-1` is returned.

Why do I get that behavior and how do I fix my code to get the right result (return of `0`)?

EDIT: changed char `mystring` to `mystring[]` (I should have made sure I typed it correcly here)

Comment: Is `char mystring` supposed to be `char mystring[]`?

Comment: Please make a [mre].

Comment: You check the return value of sscanf_s() against 0, but if you get EOF that won't work.  Seems to me the right thing is to make sure the return value is "1" and exactly 1, otherwise something odd has happened.

Comment: If you're using `sscanf_s()` instead of `sscanf()` because MSVC claimed `sscanf()` was "deprecated", be aware that's misleading claim.  `scanf()` hasn't been "deprecated" by anyone other than Microsoft and [it's still a standard C function required to be implemented](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.7).  Not only that, `sscanf_s()` is not portable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thank you for your advice. My application implements other windows specific code and is only used on windows. Even though it's not a problem for me maybe someone else finds it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `mystring` is defined as a `char`, not a string pointer.
- the argument `5` following `temp` in `sscanf_s()` should have type `rsize_t`, which is the same as `size_t`. You should specify it as `sizeof(temp)`.
- you should specify the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array in the format string, to avoid the counter-intuitive behavior of `sscanf_s` in case of overflow.
- `sscanf_s` returns `1` if it can convert and store the string. Testing `!= 0` will also accept `EOF` which is an input failure, for which the contents of `temp` is indeterminate.

Here is a modified version:

```c
const char *mystring = "STR1,STR2";
char temp[5];

if (sscanf_s(mystring, "%4[^,]", temp, sizeof temp) == 1) {
    if (strcmp(temp, "STR1") == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else
    if (strcmp(temp, "STR2") == 0) {
        return 1; 
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** The OP uses Microsoft Visual Studio, which seems to have a non-conforming implementation of the so-called *secure* stream functions. Here is a citation from their [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sscanf-s-sscanf-s-l-swscanf-s-swscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019):

> The `sscanf_s` function reads data from buffer into the location that's given by each argument. The arguments after the format string specify pointers to variables that have a type that corresponds to a type specifier in format. Unlike the less secure version `sscanf`, a buffer size parameter is required when you use the type field characters `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. The buffer size in characters must be supplied as an additional parameter immediately after each buffer parameter that requires it. For example, if you are reading into a string, the buffer size for that string is passed as follows:
>
> ```
> wchar_t ws[10];
> swscanf_s(in_str, L"%9s", ws, (unsigned)_countof(ws)); // buffer size is 10, width specification is 9
> ```
>
> The buffer size includes the terminating null. A width specification field may be used to ensure that the token that's read in will fit into the buffer. If no width specification field is used, and the token read in is too big to fit in the buffer, nothing is written to that buffer.
>
> In the case of characters, a single character may be read as follows:
>
> ```
> wchar_t wc;
> swscanf_s(in_str, L"%c", &wc, 1);
> ```
>
> This example reads a single character from the input string and then stores it in a wide-character buffer. When you read multiple characters for non-null terminated strings, unsigned integers are used as the width specification and the buffer size.
>
> ```
> char c[4];
> sscanf_s(input, "%4c", &c, (unsigned)_countof(c)); // not null terminated
> ```
>
> This example reads a single character from the input string and then stores it in a wide-character buffer. When you read multiple characters for non-null terminated strings, unsigned integers are used as the width specification and the buffer size.
>
> ```
> char c[4];
> sscanf_s(input, "%4c", &c, (unsigned)_countof(c)); // not null terminated
> ```

This specification is incompatible with the C Standard, that specifies the type of the width arguments to be `rsize_t` and type `rsize_t` to be the same type as `size_t`.

As a conclusion, for improved portability, one should avoid using these *secure* functions and use the standard functions correctly, with the length prefix to prevent buffer overruns.

You can prevent the Visual Studio warning about deprecation of `sscanf` by inserting this definition before including `<stdio.h>`:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  // let me use standard functions
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out several errors! The `4` in `%4[^,]` resolved my actual problem, but I will fix the other ones, too.

Comment: I replaced `5` by `sizeof(temp)` and now I get this warning:
`warning C4477: 'sscanf_s' : format string '%4[^,]' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int', but variadic argument 3 has type 'size_t'`

Should this actually be `(unsigned)sizeof(temp)` or is the `5` fine?

Comment: @Freakwave: `sscanf_s` expects the size argument to have type `rsize_t` which is the same as `size_t`.  The warning issued by MS Visual Studio is incorrect. Microsoft's compiler uses a non-standard implementation of `sscanf_s`. On this platform, it seems you must cast the size as `(unsigned)sizeof(temp)`, but if you specify the maximum length with `%4[^,]`, you can just use `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2):

edited per the comment from chqrlie

regarding:

```
if(sscanf_s(mystring, "%[^,]",temp, 5) != 0){
```

The input format conversion specifier: `%[..]` always appends a NUL byte to the end of the input.  So the input format conversion specifier should be: "%4[^,]"  The result after the correction is:

```
if(sscanf_s(mystring, "%4[^,]",temp, 5) != 0){
```

also, no matter how many times this code snippet is executed, the returned value wnce the other problems are corrected will ALWAYS be `STR1`

regarding the statement;

```
char mystring = "STR1,STR2";
```

This is not a valid statement.  Suggest:

```
char *mystring = "STR1,STR2";  // notice the '*'
```

--or--

```
char mystring[] = "STR1,STR2";  // notice the '[]'
```

Comment: The argument following `temp` in `sscanf_s` is the number of elements of the destination array, not the max length. The maximum length is specified in the format string as `sscanf_s(mystring, "%4[^,]", temp, sizeof(temp))`

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the `char mystring` declaration. The `4` in `%4[^,]` has resolved my problem. But because @chqrlie's answer points out other problems in my code, I will accept his answer.